# Alternate approach to WITH CTE and large UNION query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, sql-insert

I'd like to rework a script I've been given.

The way it currently works is via a WITH CTE using a large number of UNIONs.

**Current setup**

We're taking one record from a source table, inserting it into a destination table once with [Name] A then inserting it again with [Name] B. Essentially creating multiple rows in the destination, albeit with different [Name].

An example of one transaction would be to take this row from [Source]:

```
ID [123] Name [Red and Green]
```

The results of my current set up in the [Destination] is:

```
ID [123] Name [Red]
ID [123] Name [Green]
```

**Current logic**

Here's a simplified version of the current logic:

```
WITH CTE
AS  
             
(SELECT ID, 
'Red' AS [Name]
FROM [Source_Table]
WHERE [Name] = 'Red and Green'

UNION ALL
              
SELECT ID, 
'Green' AS [Name] 
FROM [Source_Table]
WHERE [Name] = 'Red and Green')


INSERT INTO [Destination_Table]  
(ID, 
[Name])
SELECT ID, 
[Name]
FROM CTE;
```

The reason I'd like to rework this is when we get a new [Name], we have to manually add another portion of code into our (ever increasing) UNION, to make sure it gets picked up.

**What I've considered**

What I was considering was setting up a WHILE LOOP (or CURSOR) running off a control table, where we could store all of the [Names]. However, I'm not sure if this would be the best approach and I'm not too familiar yet with LOOPS/CURSORS. Also, Wouldn't be too sure of how to stop the loop once all [Name]s had been completed.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Please do not post images of code. Code is text and should be posted in code fences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduce a new table called Color_List which just contains one row for each possible color. Then do this:

```
with cte as
(
    select
        st.ID,
        c.colorname
    from
        Source_Table s
    inner join
        Color_List c
    on
        CHARINDEX(c.colorname, s.[Name]) > 0
)

insert into Destination_Table
(
    ID,
    [Name]
)
select
    ID,
    colorname
from
    cte
```

The benefit of this method is that you aren't hard-coding any color names in the query. All the color names (and presumably there can be many more than two) get maintained in the Color_List table.

Comment: Thanks. I chose to use this as it seemed fairly simple and I liked the idea of having a separate control table.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `cross apply` to duplicate the rows:

```
insert into [destination_table]  (id, name)
select x.*
from source_table s
cross apply (values (id, 'Red'), (id, 'Green')) x(id, name)
where name = 'Red and Green'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use string_split to split the values apart.  First replace the ' and ' with a pipe '|'.  Then do a string split on the vertical pipe.

```
drop table if exists #tTEST;
go
select * INTO #tTEST from (values 
(1, '[123]', 'Name', '[Red and Green]')) V(ID, testCol, nameCol, stringCol);

select ID, testCol, nameCol, 
       case when left([value], 1)!='[' then concat('[',[value]) else 
        case when right([value], 1)!=']' then concat([value], ']') else [value] end end valCol
from #tTEST t
     cross apply string_split(replace(t.stringCol, ' and ', '|'), '|');
```

Results

```
ID  testCol nameCol valCol
1   [123]   Name    [Red]
1   [123]   Name    [Green]
```